# How to mock .collect method PowerMock Junit

Tags: junit, powermock

I need to know how can I mock a method which uses .collect(java 8) method, below is the method

```
//return data
public String getData(List<Node> nodes)
{
    return nodes.stream().map(node->
        getService().compare(new Reference()).collect(Collectors.joining(~));
 }

protected getService()
{
    return service;
}
```

I can mock service like

```
@Mock //mocking service
Service service
```

now how can I mock

```
getService().compare(new Reference()).collect(Collectors.joining(~));
```

Compare method returns CompareRef object. I can use PowerMock.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would recommend to mock the `compare()` method, not `collect()`.

Because you work with a stream you may have some nodes. To emulate the behaviour with multiply call of `compare()` with the same `Reference` object you may try this variant:

```
final CompareRef expectedCompareRef1 = new CompareRef();
final CompareRef expectedCompareRef2 = new CompareRef();
final CompareRef expectedCompareRef3 = new CompareRef();

when(service.compare(eq(new Reference())).thenReturn(expectedCompareRef1).thenReturn(expectedCompareRef2).thenReturn(expectedCompareRef3);
```

then call you `getData()` method:

```
final List<Nodes> givenNodes = new ArrayList<>();
givenNodes.add(node1);
givenNodes.add(node2);
givenNodes.add(node3);

final String actualResult = myInstance.getData(givenNodes);
Assert.assertEquals("TODO: expectedResult", actualResult);
```

As result the stream will collect all your test `expectedCompareRefN` objects.

Note, to have working `eq(new Reference())` your `Reference` class should implement `equals/hashCode` methods. Otherwise `eq(new Reference())` always be false and `thenReturn` will not return the specified expected objects.